# LinkName/alias not being recorded in the _click data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, email-tracking

I'm running into an issue where a campaign that has been sending for the last few months seems to not have the LinkNames that were clicked being recorded.

When we launched this project, we did our testing and confirmed that aliases were correctly being written to the click data view. We based our query to pull clickers on this LinkName/alias, but now we are getting inconsistent results with the query, because many records on the _Click data view have the url and linkContent for the specific link we're interested in, but not the actual LinkName/alias.

The url we're interested in only exists in one email. I have confirmed that the alias is still on that link in the email and have confirmed through tracking that people have actually clicked on it.

What would cause the LinkName/alias to not be recorded along with the URL and LinkContent, especially because at one point in the past, the LinkName was being recorded?

Comment: Are the alias values static or are you using AMPscript in them?

Comment: The alias is static in this case.

Comment: if the click came from the text version it would not have an alias, text clicks most likely come from security bots on the ESP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After opening a case with SFMC support, we were provided this info:

> "The reason the link alias is not displayed is because the link is
>   within an impression region for impression region tracking. When a
>   link is within an impression region it is assigned to the impression
>   region and the Link Name (Alias) is not assigned to the link."

We did not catch this originally because there was an ad-hoc send at the beginning of this project that used the same alias tag, with no impression region tracking, so it looked like the opted-out subscribers were being queried correctly.

Our solution was to update our query to no longer use LinkName/alias, but instead target the URL field on _Click data view.

You learn something new every day!

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I wonder if there is a solution for this when we want to use a unique identifier for the email instead of having to use the URL (as it might not be unique).

Answer (score 0):

Alias and Impression Region names can be obtained by taking the ClickImpression data extract. This data extract has a record of all the clicks made, even if it was not on an Impression Region. It has a field for ImpressionRegionName and Alias so both can be obtained. It also has all the fields available in Click data view.